# How to perform action when the time changes Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, datetime

My app is supposed to perform an action whenever the time changes (every minute, not every second). The way that I am achieving this is by creating a `Timer` object, like so:

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Although this way works it doesn't look very professional because the app doesn't perform the update exactly when the time changes and instead depends on the precise moment the object was created. For example, if the `Timer` object was created at 10:10:30, then the update will only be performed 30 seconds after the minute changes.

Is there a way that I can know that the minute of the time on the phone changes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By using UILocalNotification you can manage your logic internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can schedule the first timer's fire at a specific time, and that time could be the next round minute. Here is an example (copy-and-paste to a playgroung):

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

let cal = NSCalendar.current

var comps = cal.dateComponents([.era, .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: Date())
comps.minute = comps.minute! + 1

let nextMinute = cal.date(from: comps)

let timer = Timer(fire: nextMinute!, interval: 60, repeats: true) { _ in
    print("Minute change")
}

RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Note that the timer will not fire if the app is in the background.